# Javascript promise resolved by keyboard event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to target the keyboard event to resolve my promise, but it's not working anymore.

The function below is to compare the key I give it in the param with the one the user typed:

```
function compareKey(a, b) {


if (a && b) {
    (a == b) ? output("it matched"): output("it did not match");
}
}
```

The following function is to execute the `compareKey` function right after the user typed a key:

```
function KeyCatcher(a, ck) {

var touche = null;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {

    if (ev) {
        touche = ev.key;
    }

})
    if (touche != null) {
       ck(a, touche);
    }
}
```

Here I declare a promise that will help me wait for the keyboard event:

```
var keyBoardEventCatch = function(a) {
output("promise");
return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    KeyCatcher(a, resolve);
});
}

var whenRandom = keyBoardEventCatch('a');
```

Here is where I execute the promise:

```
whenRandom
.then(compareKey);


function output(a) {
console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: The KeyCatcher function makes no sense, when called it adds an event listener then returns because touche will always be null.

Comment: This is not a promise issue, it's an event listener misuse. Why do you even need a promise? Seems like your just waiting for input, that will trigger the event.

Comment: 1. What Zac said, you are returning the key before the event is triggered. 2. Don't use promises with continuous events like keydown handlers. Either just use addEventListener directly or use a stream based design pattern like RXjs instead of promises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the way you have written it, the resolve function is never called. Look at your KeyCatcher function. You are adding an event listener and passing a function to be called **at the time the event happens**. Everything outside of that callback functions is executed immediately, including

```
if (touche != null) {
  ck (a, touche);
}
```

At this point, touche will always be null, as the callback function hasn't been called yet. to fix this, move that block of code into your callback function.

Your next issue comes with passing the captured key to compareKey function. Resolve only accepts one argument, so you need to alter your input. Pass an object or an array if you want to send multiple variables.

Answer (score 0):

As others said the problem is the KeyCatcher function, the code doesnt make sense. Do this instead:

```
function KeyCatcher(a, ck) {
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
  if (ev && String.fromCharCode(ev.key)==a) {//i think that what KeyCatcher is supposed to do
    ck(a,ev.key);
  }
});
}
```

Also Promises can just be fired once, keys can be pressed quite often. So you may implement your own promise like:

```
function infinitePromise(creator){
    this.res=[];
    this.rej=[];
    creator(this.resolve,this.reject);
}
infinitePromise.prototype={
   res:[],
   rej:[],
   resolve:function(arg...){
     this.res.forEach(func=>func(...arg));
   },
   reject:function(arg...){
     this.rej.forEach(func=>func(...arg));
   },
   then:function(func){
      this.res.push(func);
   }
   //...
}
```

So you can do:

```
prom=new infinitePromise(function(resolve){ KeyCatcher("a",resolve);});
prom.then(console.log);
```

Comment: @ADLefa youre welcome ;) . As i wrote the first answer and also solved your promise problem, it would be fair to at least give an upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper to listen for events once. Once because the promises only emits once as well...

```js
function fromEvent<T extends Event>(element: EventTarget, eventName: string): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>(resolve => {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, (event: Event) => resolve(event as T), {once : true});
    });
}
```

Then you can capture any event, here I catch the keydown.

```js
fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(window.document, 'keydown')
    .then((event) => {
        console.log('Key down', event);
    });
```

Test [it here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMATnAtgUQG4FMxQA8AKorgB5T4AmAzojvlAHwAUuANrukwFyIA5ONVwAaMngICAhj360oKGGADmASn4AFNOhi1cJZogDeAKEQXEKXFBAokYXAHdE2jHoPE212nA55EAF4jM0swsi4eAgA6aWpqRgIAGT0qRxR2SSgZHnFMvgYstSCjHz88fIJEaXpiNXFjBAhcRH5FEFwAXzUAbnNLbr7O01NUDESiAGlcAE8AIzhpFASstidlajgnaM2IECiocQByAGtZzacwI7V+i2ioAAt8VkqoYuCTW-CIBF8uaI4cBUrCO0xmiAuV3EuCKfTCg1MQA)

Comment: I would suggest `fromEvent<K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>(element: HTMLElement, eventName: K): Promise<HTMLElementEventMap[K]>`. Then you can also avoid the type assertions and simplify to `addEventListener(eventName, resolve, {once: true})`

Comment: You can have custom events which are not part of the HTMLElementEventMap's key, in which case you wont be able to listen for the events. Otherwise your version should work fine  `function fromHtmlEvent<K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>(element: HTMLElement, eventName: K): Promise<HTMLElementEventMap[K]>{
    return new Promise<HTMLElementEventMap[K]>(resolve => element.addEventListener(eventName, (event) => resolve(event), {once : true}));
}` The best would be to add a generic value, to infer it's type depending on if it does extends HTMLElement to then retrieve Events based on the key